ECDsa fails in Azure succeeds elsewhere
I have the following two methods that work both on Mac and on PC. When I deploy it to Azure Web App then it throws a Cryptographic Exception. I validated that the key is correct and accurate. I am a little stumped on what else I could to do fix this.
I am running the app in a windows environment with NET Core 8. Hosted as a WebApi in Azure.
The error message specifically is "The system cannot find the file specified."
public string GenerateAppleSecret(string TeamId, string keyId, string serviceId, string key)
{
    var now = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1);
    ReadOnlySpan<byte> keyAsSpan = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
    var prvKey = ECDsa.Create();
    prvKey.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(keyAsSpan, out var read);
    return new JwtBuilder()
        .WithAlgorithm(new ES256Algorithm(ECDsa.Create(), prvKey))
        .AddHeader("kid", keyId)
        .ExpirationTime(now.AddDays(4).UtcDateTime)
        .IssuedAt(now.UtcDateTime)
        .Issuer(TeamId)
        .Audience("https://appleid.apple.com")
        .Subject(serviceId)
        .Encode();
}

private string CreateWeatherKitAuthToken(string teamId, string keyId, string serviceId, string privateKey)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(privateKey) || privateKey.Length < 5)
   {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid Private Key");
   }

   byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);

   // Create a cross-platform ECDsa instance and import the private key
   ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create();  // Cross-platform
   ecdsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _); // Import PKCS8 formatted key

   // Define the header
   var header = new JwtHeader(new SigningCredentials(
       new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa), SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256)
   );
   header["kid"] = keyId; // Apple key identifier (kid)

   // Define the current time and expiration time for the token (in seconds since epoch)
   var currentTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
   var expirationTime = currentTime + 3600; // Token expires in 1 hour

   // Define the payload
   var payload = new JwtPayload
{
   { "iss", teamId },           // Issuer (Apple Team ID)
   { "iat", currentTime },       // Issued at time
   { "exp", expirationTime },    // Expiration time
   { "sub", serviceId }          // Subject (Service ID)
};

   // Create the JWT token
   var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

   // Return the token string
   var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
   return handler.WriteToken(jwtToken);
}

Stack Trace:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import (System.Security.Cryptography, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngPkcs8.ImportPkcs8 (System.Security.Cryptography, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngPkcs8.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey (System.Security.Cryptography, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsaCng.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey (System.Security.Cryptography, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.PemKeyHelpers.ImportPem (System.Security.Cryptography, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at WeatherKitApi.GetECDsaPrivateKey (CosplayCorps.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\CosplayCorps.Business\Api\Apple\WeatherKitApi.cs:80)


Well I know this took me a while to figure out myself. I found the fix was to set the following variable in my app service in azure.
WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE = 1
